How can I view the size of each email in Gmail Android application?
How can I view the size of each email in the Gmail Android application?
I am able to see the size of some emails (e.g., emails located in the trash) via Google Drive's cleaning feature, but I can't see for other emails:
 

I don't know a way to directly see the size of individual messages in Gmail-for-Android however, if the goal is to identify messages based on their size perhaps using the search interface to return messages filtered by size would be helpful.
Search by Size Syntax



Operator
Gmail Syntax                                                                                                             




Greater than
larger:


Less than
smaller:


Megabyte
M


Kilobyte
K


Byte
          ( Blank )



Example Searches

Archived messages greater than 5 MB:
-in:inbox larger:5M 


Messages between 500 KB and 2 MB located anywhere except Spam and Trash:
larger:500K smaller:2M



